# How to use angularjs to show media?

Tags: angularjs

In Html, we can use

```
<video src="movie.ogg" controls="controls">
您的浏览器不支持 video 标签。
</video>
```

show a video, but if `src="{{$videoUrl}}"`, it has some errors,

```
Error: [$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate: {{$videoUrl}}
Error: [$sce:insecurl] Blocked loading resource from url not allowed by $sceDelegate policy.
```

How to fixed it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to indicate that you trust the url:

```
    $scope.videoUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(yourUrl);
```

Inject `$sce` in order to use this. The error tells you that you have an $sce insecure error.